# Remove empty spaces or NaNs from lists in column of lists in Python/Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
   A  B
1  1  [a,b,d,d]
2  6  [,1,4,d,g]
3  a  [w,1,NaN,x,y,2]
```

I need to remove the blank in row 2, and the NaN in row 3 to get:

```
   A  B
1  1  [a,b,d,d]
2  6  [1,4,d,g]
3  a  [w,1,x,y,2]
```

I think applying some kind of lambda list comprehension?

```
df.B=df.B.apply(lambda x: x if x not in ['',np.NaN])
```

but not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work on your comprehension skills :)

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, ['a','b','d','d']],
        [6, ['',1,4,'d','g']],
        ['a', ['w',1,np.nan,'x','y',2]]
    ], columns=['A', 'B'])

df.B.apply(lambda l: [x for x in l if x not in ['', np.nan]])
```

where `l` is the current list and `x` are elements of `l`.

Comment: BINGO.  I've done this many times and just fell into one of those rat traps.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Just letting you know that I appreciate the pun +1